# How to start python file on startup using linux?

Tags: python, linux

I have a python file that I want to start up automatically using raspberry pi. I have searched this up a few times but have found either outdated answers or answers that are very unclear. Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: It depends what init system your distro uses. For Raspbian you can create systemd service unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do so. I couldn't find anything on stackoverflow tho so here you go:

Using the "/etc/rc.local" is probably the quickest/easiest solution:

You have to open rc.local and add whatever you want to execute on startup. In your case something like this:

> sudo nano /etc/rc.local

then add the following to the end of the file

> sudo python /home/pi/python-program.py &

while "/home/pi/python-program.py" needs to point to your python program

you can find more explanations and other methods here:
https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/#local

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/thagrol/Guides/blob/main/boot.pdf) is a good stuff for running a programm at start up in five way